# FirebaseListAdapter, ¿TextView dentro de populateView?

Tags: java, android, firebase

¿Por qué no me aparece nada en la emulacion con este código?
No se como y donde debe estar creado el TextView al que se le setea el texto 's'. No entiendo su funcionamiento, gracias.

```
public class Cursos extends AppCompatActivity {  
    Firebase rootRef = PantallaPrincipal.rootRef;  
    ListView lista_cursos;  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cursos);  
        lista_cursos = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_cursos);  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onStart() {  
        super.onStart();  
        Firebase cursosRef = rootRef.child("Cursos");  
        FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,String.class,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursosRef){  
            @Override  
            protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {  
                TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);  
                textView.setText(s);  
            }  
        };  
        lista_cursos.setAdapter(adapter);  
    }
}
```

Intento hacer que aparezcan los datos que hay en la DataBase de Firebase en un listView.

Comment: Victor, hay reglas de formato para realizar una pregunta. Esto es importante para poder entender tu problema, seguir los formatos por favor.

Comment: yo cree algo parecido, pero hice que lo de FireBase se colocará en un TextView, [Así](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2uKoK.jpg). No se si quieres lograr algo similar

Comment: Agregar el codigo de como lo implementaste le ayudaria bastante al usuario

Answer (score 0):

Coloca tu código en el `onCreate` y accesa a tu `TextView` a través del `View` que llega como argumento en el `populateView`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    lista_cursos = new ListView(this);

    FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter ... {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(s));
        }
    };
    lista_cursos.setAdapter(adapter);
    setContentView(lista_cursos); 
}
```

Comment: Mmmm pero... ¿Por que no me funciona?

Comment: ¿Ha funcionado en el `onCreate`? o sigue sin darte resultados.

Comment: Probaré gracias, pero Android Studio es un lío... No hice nada y ahora me tira un error u_u